# Response cache vary by user claim

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have a `Claim` in my `ClaimsPrincipal` object, it contains a `boolean`, and I need the response cache to vary by this `boolean`.

In MVC 5 I could easily do this with a `VaryByCustom` string, but I can't figure out how to solve this issue in .NET Core.